# Getting required option from Namespace in Python

Tags: python, argparse

I create a ArgumentParser like this:

```
argpr = ArgumentParser()
argpr.add_argument('--long-c', '-c', required=True, dest='long_c')
```

If I there exist a json configfile I add configuration to a Namespace:

```
cfg = argparse.Namespace()
if json_dict is not None:
    cfg.long_c = json['long-c']
print vars(cfg)
```

Then I use the Namespace as an argument to the argument parser like this:

```
use_cfg = argpr.parse_args(namespace=cfg)
```

I can see that I get a value in to my Namespace object and because of that I expect that ArgumentParser.parse_args finds long_c in my Namespace object but I get:

```
argument --long-c/-c is required
```

Am I doing something wrong? Is this a bug or is it expected behavior? Any suggestions on how to get this working is welcome =)

Thank you in advance

EDITS:
- Fixed typo.
- Changed for namespace to Namespace object.
- Clarified my use of the Namespace object and my expectations.

Comment: Do you have the same `argparese` typo in your code or is it just in your question?

Comment: @AndréLaszlo ... sorry corrected that.

Comment: @ziddarth why would I do that? I want my arguments from the comandline and I expect parse_args to find the value in my provided Namespace object.

Comment: Using a `namespace` parameter like this is equivalent to specifying a default value.  Try it without the 'required=True'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I subclassed `ArgumentParser` to do what you want it to do.

```
import json
from argparse import ArgumentParser

class ConfigurableArgumentParser(ArgumentParser):

    def __init__(self, config_file, *args, **kwargs):
        self.config = json.load(config_file)
        super(ConfigurableArgumentParser, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def add_argument(self, *args, **kwargs):
        store_action = super(ConfigurableArgumentParser, self).add_argument(
            *args, **kwargs)
        dest = store_action.dest
        if dest in self.config:
            store_action.default = self.config[dest]
            store_action.required = False
        return store_action
```

This argument parser takes an additional constructor argument, `config_file` which is supposed to be a file object pointing to a JSON config file. The `add_argument` method is modified to use default values from the config file if they exist, in which case `required` will also be set to `False`.

Usage:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    from StringIO import StringIO

    # config_file = open('my_config.json')
    config_file = StringIO('{"long_c": "1"}')

    parser = ConfigurableArgumentParser(config_file)
    parser.add_argument('--long-c', '-c',
                        required=True, dest='long_c', type=int)
    namespace = parser.parse_args()
    print namespace
    # Output:
    # Namespace(long_c=1)
```

Note that the type is still handled the way it should and the JSON string is automatically converted to an `int`.

Comment: Note that your add_argument() method doesn't return anything.

Answer (score 3):

There's nothing wrong with how you are creating and using your Namespace (after you made the corrections), but as André Laszlo mentioned, your expectations are wrong:

> ...I expect that ArgumentParser.parse_args finds long_c in my
>   Namespace object but I get:
>
> ```
> argument --long-c/-c is required
> ```

It's easy to prove that argparse doesn't work like that:

```
import argparse as ap

argpr = ap.ArgumentParser()
argpr.add_argument('--long-c', '-c', required=True, dest='long_c')

cfg = ap.Namespace()  
print(cfg)

name_space = argpr.parse_args(namespace=cfg)
print(name_space.long_c)
print(name_space)  #name_space and cfg are different names for the same object 

--output:--
$ python3.4 1.py -c 4
Namespace()
4
Namespace(long_c='4')
```

(Note that if you want the stored value to be an int, then you can add `type=int` to add_argument() )

Now with the cfg namespace already having a value for `long_c`:

```
import argparse as ap

argpr = ap.ArgumentParser()
json_dict = {'long-c': 5}

cfg = ap.Namespace()

if json_dict:
   cfg.long_c = json_dict['long-c']

print(cfg)

argpr.add_argument('--long-c', '-c', required=True, dest='long_c')
name_space = argpr.parse_args(namespace=cfg)
print(name_space.long_c)

print(name_space)  #name_space and cfg are different names for the same object 

--output:--
$ python3.4 1.py -c 4
Namespace(long_c=5)
4
Namespace(long_c='4')
```

But...

```
$ python3.4 1.py
Namespace(long_c=5)
usage: 1.py [-h] --long-c LONG_C
1.py: error: the following arguments are required: --long-c/-c
```

To get the behavior you want, you need to make the `-c` option *optional* if the json_dict already has a value for it, something like this:

```
cfg = ap.Namespace()
required = True

if json_dict:
    val = json_dict.get('long-c', False) 

    if val:
        cfg.long_c = val
        required = False

print(cfg)

argpr.add_argument('--long-c', '-c', required=required, dest='long_c')
```

Answer (score 1):

[`Namespace`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html#the-namespace-object)s are not for passing arguments but for storing the results. You need to pass the configuration in the `args` parameter. I think this is what you are after:

```
cfg = []
if json_dict is not None:
    cfg.extend(('-c', json['long-c']))
use_cfg = argpr.parse_args(cfg)
```

I see what you are trying to do, but I don't think `argparse` will inspect the namespace for required arguments the way you want it to. Normally you don't need to give a `namespace` argument, but it can be nice if you want the parsed arguments to be assigned to an existing object.

Also, if you *do* want to explicitly create a `Namespace`, be sure to instantiate it:

```
# use this:
argparse.Namespace()
# not this:
argparse.Namespace
```

Otherwise you will end up assigning attributes to the `Namespace` class itself.

Also read the note on [`required`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html#required):

> Note: Required options are generally considered bad form because users
>   expect options to be optional, and thus they should be avoided when
>   possible.

Comment: I have argparse.Namespace() ... typo again. Thanks for the answer.